# Search an entire google sheet, return a value from matching cell relative to the position of the matching cell

Tags: google-sheets, index-match

I have a google sheet that's laid out like a wall calendar.

I'd like to take data from two cells relative to each calendar date in this calendar view and add them to a single row in another sheet.

I've added notes with expected results in the "entries" sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eTtmNR-9dbWG_bDhzpWgza5idUphodmJsI6sS0DU0og/edit?usp=sharing

I explored vlookup and index match, but they didn't do the trick. I had a hard time searchign both rows and columns, matching the dates, and based on that match, selecting the relative cell.

Comment: If the two cells indicate row and column, then index() can accept the results from 2 match() functions, one for the column and one for the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out in Entries!B2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(BYROW(A2:A32,LAMBDA(day,
SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(December!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet,
IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️","December!"&ADDRESS(
ROW(sheet)+{1,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3})),)))),"❄️"))),
LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))))
```

This formula will spill in the range B2:C32 so make sure that it's empty.

**UPDATE:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(MAP(BYROW(A2:A32,LAMBDA(day,
SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(December!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet,
IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️",BYROW("December!"&ADDRESS(
ROW(sheet)+{1,0;2,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3}),
LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄️",row)))),)))),"❄️"))),
LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))),"select Col1, Col2, Col3"))
```

Comment: Absolutely incredible. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to expand the function to include another cell. I added `,ROW(sheet)+{2,0}`: 


`=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(BYROW(A2:A32,LAMBDA(day,
SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(December!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet,
IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️","December!"&ADDRESS(
ROW(sheet)+{1,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3},ROW(sheet)+{2,0})),)))),"❄️"))),
LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))))`


Is there a systematic way I can approach expanding on this function to include one or more cells? 


I'm getting this error:
#NUM
"Function ADDRESS parameter 3 value is 6. Valid values are between 1 and 4 inclusive."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250320/discussion-between-user2872447-and-ztiaa).

Comment: As I've applied this formula for each month of the year, I'm getting inconsistent results in the "Entries" tab. For example, December and October show the results accurately (the content is mapped to the day), but November and September do not. I haven't yet been able to troubleshoot this and would appreciate another pair of eyes. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQiI0D5VG5BD1AGdmW4_4kLFfMLlgDfREyHkmHnCbGk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(N(A2:A33)), 
 SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(December!B4:Z20&"​"&December!B5:Z21&"×​"&December!E4:AC20), 
 "​"), 3, 0, 2, 0)&"", {2, 3}, ), "×", )))
```

[image]