# google sheets: filter results based on multiple filters, across a row-column search

Tags: google-sheets

In `Entries` Sheet, I have rows with Date, Note, and Number columns

In `Reports` Sheet, I'd like to show a filtered list of Notes based on the Date and Number columns from Sheet 1.

I've added notes to the [example google sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eTtmNR-9dbWG_bDhzpWgza5idUphodmJsI6sS0DU0og/edit#gid=2041138436)

Note that the layout in `Entries` is a bit odd. Right now, each month has corresponding columns and those are laid out horizontally. I'd expect to have all the dates and their corresponding columns show in a signle set of columns, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Making that happen is not essential as I think there are pros/cons to changing it. Open to feedback.

Relevant to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755235/search-an-entire-google-sheet-return-a-value-from-matching-cell-relative-to-the/74755507)

I tried various lookup, index, and match methods and did not succeed.

Comment: sheet link is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out in B3:

```
=LAMBDA(notes,IFNA(FILTER(notes,notes<>"")))
(INDEX(TRIM(Entries!A2:ZZZ),,MATCH(B1,Entries!1:1,0)+1))
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
=IFNA(
  QUERY(
    BYCOL({1,2},
      LAMBDA(
        offset,
        INDEX(Entries!A2:ZZZ,,MATCH(B1,Entries!1:1,0)+offset))),
   "select Col1"&IF(B2="",," where Col2 = "&B2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ztiaa. It works perfectly for the Month filter, but it seems to show the results regardless of whether the Number filter is selected. My goal is to show results based on the Month and Number filters (and show no results if either is not selected). 

Would the solution be to add another piece of the function such as this one?
(INDEX(TRIM(Entries!A2:ZZZ),,MATCH(*B2*,Entries!1:1,0)+1))

Comment: This is so helpful – thank you ztiaa!

Comment: I was able to use your first function for something else. I used it to output the column of Numbers associated with the Date in `Entries`. I'm now trying to plot that set of numbers on a chart, but when I select that number range I'm getting an "Invalid Type" error. Can the function be changed to output a set of numbers usable in the a chart?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Could you replicate the issue in the sheet you've shared? I would also encourage you to change the sharing settings to allow anyone to EDIT so it will be faster to check.

Comment: Notes and permissions updated in the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eTtmNR-9dbWG_bDhzpWgza5idUphodmJsI6sS0DU0og/edit#gid=2041138436

Comment: see updated formula. I converted the result to numbers by multiplying it by -1 twice. `--notes` instead of `notes`.

Comment: How might we modify this function to reference a different column in the "Entries" sheet, e.g. the column titled "Extra" (cols D and H)?