# Search an entire google sheet, return a value from matching cell relative to the position of the matching cell – Follow U

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I had originally asked the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755235/search-an-entire-google-sheet-return-a-value-from-matching-cell-relative-to-the). "I have a google sheet that's laid out like a wall calendar.

I'd like to take data from two cells relative to each calendar date in this calendar view and add them to a single row in another sheet."

A user provided a function that worked almost perfectly, but there is a small issue with it: As I've applied this formula for each month of the year, I'm getting inconsistent results in the "Entries" tab. For example, December and October show the results accurately (the content is mapped to the day), but November and September do not. I haven't yet been able to troubleshoot this and would appreciate another pair of eyes. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQiI0D5VG5BD1AGdmW4_4kLFfMLlgDfREyHkmHnCbGk/edit#gid=434311882

Here is the current function:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(MAP(BYROW(A2:A32,LAMBDA(day,SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(January!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet, IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️",BYROW("January!"&ADDRESS(ROW(sheet)+{1,0;2,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3}), LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄️",row)))),)))),"❄️"))), LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))),"select Col1, Col2, Col3"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adjust the Range Based on the Number of Days Per Month

Your given function worked fine for months with 31 days. You just need to adjust the formula when applying to other months.

For example, for November: `change AY2:AY32 to AY2:AY31` since AY31 is the last cell containing the last day for the month of November.

[image]

It should look like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(MAP(BYROW(AY2:AY31,LAMBDA(day,
SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(November!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet,
IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️",BYROW("November!"&ADDRESS(
ROW(sheet)+{1,0;2,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3}),
LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄️",row)))),)))),"❄️"))),
LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))),"select Col1, Col2, Col3"))
```

The same applies for February: `change F2:F32 to F2:F28`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(MAP(BYROW(F2:F28,LAMBDA(day,
SPLIT(CONCATENATE(MAP(February!A2:Z,LAMBDA(sheet,
IF(sheet=day,JOIN("❄️",BYROW("February!"&ADDRESS(
ROW(sheet)+{1,0;2,0},COLUMN(sheet)+{0,3}),
LAMBDA(row,JOIN("❄️",row)))),)))),"❄️"))),
LAMBDA(cell,INDIRECT(cell))),"select Col1, Col2, Col3"))
```

### Output

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you have other questions.

Comment: So simple. Thanks PatrickdC

Comment: They are all working now except for April. I'm seeing this error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2. Any ideas?

Comment: That is weird. The formulas should work. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: I do apologize but I could not find anything on my side since all calendar sheets are formatted the same as well as the formulas used. It seems to me that this is a bug. You can either post another question with regards to this issue on Stack Overflow or you can file an issue report to the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: The dates in April are of March 2023!

Comment: rockinfreakshow – nice. I 1) updated it to be april, and 2) removed a rogue may date. Thank you, and thanks again PatrickdC. You guys rock.